# Can anyone show me how to write a update stored procedure in the sql server whose primary key is of type uniqueidentifier?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    
    @Category_Code nvarchar(20),
    @Category_Name nvarchar(167),
    @About_Category nvarchar(max),
    @Parent_Category_Id uniqueidentifier,
    @Is_Enable bit,
    @Is_Active bit,
    @Is_Block bit,
    @Category_Id uniqueidentifier

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Update Category 
    SET    Category_Code      = @Category_Code,
           Category_Name      = @Category_Name,
           About_Category     = @About_Category,
           Parent_Category_Id = @Parent_Category_Id,
           Is_Enable          = @Is_Enable, 
           Is_Active          = @Is_Active,
           Is_Block           = @Is_Block 
    WHERE  Category_Id        = @Category_Id
    
END
```

this is my stored procedure but it cannot update the records. Why?

Comment: How does it not update? The code looks fine. How do you use the sproc?

Answer (score 0):

Unique identifiers are one of the fundamental blocks of data modeling and well as data consumption.A GUID in SQL Server can generate unique IDs with the least probability of the exact ID being generated.GUIDs are typically 128-bit in size and 32 digits long in the pattern of 8 digits – 4 digits – 4 digits – 4 digits – 12 digits.
newid(), NewSequentialId() is inbuilt function which generates the random unique identifiers. Newid() is generates random id but the NewSequentialId() generates id in sequential manner. Try to update the unique identifiers with these in built functions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This doesn't really answer the question. Please read [answer].